# What is the run time of the following statement in big oh notation?

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, big-o

```
public int foo ( int x , int k ) {
     if ( x <= k )
         return 1;
     else
         return foo ( x / k , k ) + 1;
}
```

From my understanding, the runtime of this should equal the runtime of the conditional + the runtime of the larger if/else statement.

However, I'm having trouble determining the correct runtime of the statement "return foo(x/k, k) + 1". Would this be constant? The increase of x and k doesn't seem to have an effect on the runtime, as it is the ratio between them that is important for the outcome.

Any clarity would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Deriving the result logically seems quite tricky, but you could possibly find the answer by measuring the run time of various inputs and looking for a trend. Luckily, you don't even need time-measuring functions to do this, because the number returned by the function is the same as the number of times the function body executed. Ex. if the function returns 6, it took twice as long as when it returned 3.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive call divides `x` by `k` each time, so the complexity for k >= 2 is `O(logk(x))` - logarithm of x in base k.

For k < 2 it might not terminate (in reality, it will run out of memory or divide by zero).

Comment: well, actually -2 would terminate too